# Honda CBF600NA with 150 CCA Battery?

Tags: honda, battery

I have a Honda CBF600NA (A = ABS variant) PC43 (second generation) and my battery probably went dead recently. I'd like to buy a new one. My dead battery I've found inside the motorcycle is `GS-Yuasa YTZ10S`. I've found one replacement, `Varta TTZ10S` with very similar parameters as this GS-Yuasa, but instead of 190CCA it has 150CCA (it's the only difference). Do you think it would make sense to buy this 150CCA battery into my CBF600NA? Would 150CCA be enough to properly start the engine so that it won't result in future damages?

The reason I'm asking is that Yuasa is ~3x more expensive than other batteries, and it has a high "premium tax", which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

The CCA on a battery indicates the Cold-Crank-Amps of the battery.
It means the amount of amps the battery is able to deliver in 0 degree Celsius .

Higher CCA means better starting ability of the battery.

I did some research online and I found out that you can use anything more than 130CCA on your motorcycle without any issues.

[Click for more info](http://www.mdsbattery.co.uk/shop/productprofile.asp?ProductGroupID=1402&model=CBF600&brand=HONDA&departmentName=Motorcycle%20Batteries&departmentID=155)

Comment: I forgot to specify that I have a PC43 version (second generation) CBF600NA bike (I've updated the original post with this info). I know first generation used batteries with lower CCA, but do you think second generation also could use it?

Comment: @antonone  Oh I see. The PC43 is fuel injected unlike the older one. In that case I am not very sure if the lower CCA battery would work. I would go for the manufacturer specified values.

Comment: @antonne  Again, notice that the specification is at 0 degrees C.   How much "starting" of your motorcycle are you going to do in that temperature?  Your actual available cranking amps will be much higher as the temperature rises.